# Hide Javascript/CSS in Adobe AIR application deliverable

Tags: javascript, air

I've created an Adobe Air application that, when installed, will distribute the Javascript and CSS in the same readable format it was built with.  This doesn't surprise me, but I was hoping that there would be some option that would have Air automatically obscure the source of the application for you upon installation.

I know that I could minify it prior to building the final package but I was hoping for something a little more advanced.  Am I missing something in the Air package build process or is this just the way it's supposed to be and nothing can be done about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That surprised me when I wrote my first AIR app. But that's how it is.

Adobe AIR apps can also be written in ActionScript and that's compiled to bytecode. If you have some code in particular you want to obscure, you could move it into Flash or onto a server.

If you want to stay all in JavaScript, the usual methods of obscuring are probably about it.